# Good references for specific heats

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, material-science, polymers

Does anyone know of a good reference for specific heats?  It seems that it is no longer popular to publish values.  I am especially interested in the specific heats of polymers.

Answer (score 4):

- The [Polymer Handbook (4th Edition)](http://www.knovel.com/web/portal/browse/display?_EXT_KNOVEL_DISPLAY_bookid=1163) has heat capacity data (Chapter VI, section “Heat Capacities of High Polymers”).
- [The ATHAS Data Bank](http://athas.prz.rzeszow.pl/Default.aspx?op=db)
- A possible ancestor to the above: “The ATHAS database on heat capacities of polymers”, *Pure & App. Chem.*, 67, 1019-1026 (1945).